# How to set position for Edit form of jqGrid as center of the window

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have jqGrid with Edit and Add forms, problem is displaying left side of the jqGrid, instead of center of the window, i have tried in different ways, but not getting, here my code is..

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid({
        url: 'http://localhost:52618/Sample/GetEmployeeDetails',
        datatype: "json",
        mtype: "POST",
        colNames: ['Eno', 'Ename', 'City', 'Salary', 'Address', 'Actions'],
        colModel: [
         { name: 'Eno', index: 'Eno', width: 120, stype: 'text', height: 90, editable: true },
         { name: 'Ename', index: 'Ename', width: 150, editable: true },
         { name: 'City', index: 'City', width: 150, editable: true },
            { name: 'Salary', index: 'Salary', width: 100, height: 120, editable: true },
            { name: 'Address', index: 'Address', width: 100, height: 120, hidden: true, editable: true, editrules: { edithidden: true }, hidedlg: true },
             {
                 name: 'Actions', index: 'Actions', width: 100, height: 120, formatter: 'actions',
                 formatoptions: {
                     keys: true,
                     editformbutton: true,

                 }
             },
        ],
        rowNum: 10,
        add: true,
        addParams: { useFormatter: true },

        mtype: 'Get',
        loadonce: true,
        pager: '#jQGridDemoPager',
        viewrecords: true,
        caption: "List Employee Details",
        height: "230px",
        add: true,
    });

    jQuery("#jQGridDemo").jqGrid('navGrid', "#jQGridDemoPager", {

        add: true,
        edit: false,
        del: false

    });
});
```

Comment: _i have tried in different ways_.....you should post those too.

Comment: [link][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21846860/how-to-align-center-search-popup-in-jqgrid/21847426?noredirect=1#comment33076158_21847426

This is very easy to make. Check link given.

Answer (score 5):

There are really many ways to change the position of Add/Edit form on the window. One way is the usage of [jQuery UI position](http://jqueryui.com/position/). It allows to to set position an element relative to the window, document, another element (for example relative to the grid). You can use `beforeShowForm` or `afterShowForm` callbacks for example. To set such callbacks for both Add and Edit dialogs you can extend `$.jgrid.edit`. Try the following code

```js
$.extend(true, $.jgrid.edit, {
    recreateForm: true,
    beforeShowForm: function ($form) {
        $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").position({
            of: window, // or any other element
            my: "center center",
            at: "center center"
        });
    }
});
```

**UPDATED**: [The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CenterOfAddForm.htm) uses the above code.

Comment: I Tried this But not working, still anything should be change?

Comment: @Sanjay: You made sure an error in usage of the code which I posted. I added **UPDATED** part with the demo which uses the code. You can see that the demo work.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same requirement, so added the properties of top and left as shown below.

```
{
                    name: 'Actions', index: 'Actions', width: 35, editable: false,
                    formatter: 'actions',
                    formatoptions: {
                        keys: true,
                        delbutton: false,
                        editformbutton: true,
                        editOptions: {
                            url: '/Account/EditUser',
                            width: dbWidth,
                            top: Math.max(0, ($(window).height() / 3)),
                            left: Math.max(0, ($(window).width() / 3)),
                            closeOnEscape: true,
                            afterComplete: function (response) {
                                if (response.responseText) {
                                    alert(response.responseText);
                                    $(this).jqGrid('setGridParam', { datatype: 'json' }).trigger('reloadGrid');
                                    if (response.responseText === "Saved Successfully")
                                        $('#cData').trigger('click');
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                },
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried Oleg's way but is does not work with last version of jqGrid 5.0.2. Next code works fine for me:

```
function centerjqdialog($form) {
    $form.closest(".ui-jqdialog").position({
        of: window,
        my: "center center",
        at: "center center"
    });
}

$.jgrid.regional["ru"].edit.afterShowForm = centerjqdialog;
$.jgrid.regional["ru"].del.afterShowForm = centerjqdialog;
$.jgrid.regional["ru"].search.afterShowForm = centerjqdialog;
$.jgrid.regional["ru"].view.afterShowForm = centerjqdialog;
```

Code `regional["ru"]` replace to `regional["en"]` or something else by your taste.